# How to create Auto single Deployment release CD in azure DevOps for multiple instances of ScaleSet VM

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-vm-scale-set

I am working to create CI-CD build release piplline in Azaure DevOps. I am able to create Build successfully but now facing issue to create release CD.

I have created one ScaleSet VM in Azure DevOps and 3 instances of it.

Now, I want to create single releaes with single deployment target group that can install my IIS website application on all instances in single attempt.

Can anyone guide me for this process?

Let me know if you want more details from me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to install IIS on all instances in a single attempt, you just can change the image of the Scale Set into a new image which you create with IIS installed in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure these three instances as [Deployment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=vsts).